# Django: unable to render data returned from a view

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I've been trying to show some data in my `index.html` template with no luck.

**models.py**

```
class Appartement(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Ville_et_adresse = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    NB_de_chambre = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    NB_de_douche = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    NB_de_garage = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    NB_de_piscine = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    NB_de_cuisine = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    Superficie = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    Prix = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0)
    Description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, default=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="static/upload/", blank=True, null=True)
    actif = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.name}' 
    
    class Meta: 
        ordering = ['-id']
        verbose_name_plural =("Appartements")
```

**views.py**

```
from .models import Appartement

def index(request):
    appartement = Appartement.objects.all()
    context={'appartement':appartement}
    
    return render(request, 'index.html' , context)
```

**index.html**

```
<div class="property-item">
    <a class="property-img" href="avendre">
        <img src="{% static 'images/property/property_1.jpg'%}" alt="#">
    </a>
    ...
</div>

{% for appartement in Appartement %}
<div class="property-title-box">
    <h4><a href="avendre">{{ appartement.nom }}</a></h4>
    <div class="property-location">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
        <p>{{ Appartement.Ville_et_adresse}}</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="property-feature">
        <li> <i class="fas fa-bed"></i>
            <span>{{ Appartement.NB_de_chambre }}</span>
        </li>
        <li> <i class="fas fa-bath"></i>
            <span>{{ Appartement.NB_de_douche }}</span>
        </li>
        <li> <i class="fas fa-arrows-alt"></i>
            <span>{{ Appartement.Superficie }}</span>
        </li>
        <li> <i class="fas fa-car"></i>
            <span>{{Appartement.NB_de_piscine }}</span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="trending-bottom">

        <a class="trend-left float-left">
            <div class="trend-open">
                <p>{{ Appartement.Prix }}</p>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I use django-4 with bootstrap

Comment: Can you print `appartement` in your index function and check are you getting the data from the database?

Comment: I did as you said but nothing is displayed on the user interface

Comment: by user interface, you mean terminal where you are running `python manage.py runserver`?

Answer (score 0):

In your views you are sending all the objects in the context variable `appartement`. In the template you have used `Appartement`. Change this to

```
{% for appt in appartement %}
```

or change the context variable to `appartements` such that `context={'appartements':appartement}`, and then use in your template

```
{% for appartement in appartements %}
```

Then inside the `for` loop access each of the `appartement` instance like `{{appartement.nom}}` and so on.